# Trouble auto-generating list of links

Tags: tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

I have a page in my Wiki (v5.1.17) that is supposed to auto-generate a list of links to tiddlers that need some sort of follow up. What shows up is whatever fulfils one of two criteria: tagged "needs_followup", or title begins with "/followup/".

Here is my code:

`<$list filter="[prefix[/followup/]] [tag[followup_needed]] +[sort[title]]" variable=entry>
<$link><<entry>></$link><br/>
</$list>`

The list of items works fine actually, except that they're not clickable links.  They *look* like links -- blue and underlined -- but clicking on one doesn't actually do anything.  Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The list of items works fine actually, except that they're not clickable links.

The problem arises because you have changed the variable in which the list widget stores titles. Usually [the list widget stores](https://tiddlywiki.com/#ListWidget) the current title in a variable named `<<currentTiddler>>`:

This variable name is well known by other widgets, e.g. the link widget [will look for this variable](https://tiddlywiki.com/#LinkWidget) when no `to` attribute is specified.

However, your list widget instance stores the current title in a variable named `entry`, which is not understood by the `<$link>` widget.

> They look like links -- blue and underlined -- but clicking on one doesn't actually do anything.

Actually, they are "real" links and also navigate once clicked: The link widget will resolve the tiddler where your code is in as `<<currentTiddler>>` and try to link to this tiddler (which looks like it is not linking at all because you probably have no scroll effect).

> Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Solution 1) Hence the solution is to add the `to`-attribute and set it to `<<entry>>`:

```
<$list filter="[prefix[/followup/]] [tag[followup_needed]] +[sort[title]]" variable=entry>
    <$link to=<<entry>>><<entry>></$link><br/>
</$list>
```

Solution 2) Instead of setting `to` you could also do the following:

```
<$list filter="[prefix[/followup/]] [tag[followup_needed]] +[sort[title]]" variable=entry>
    <$set name="currentTiddler" value=<<entry>>>
        <$link><<entry>></$link><br/>
    </$set>
</$list>
```

Solution 3) Or you could remove the `variable=entry` altogether

```
<$list filter="[prefix[/followup/]] [tag[followup_needed]] +[sort[title]]">
  <$link><<currentTiddler>></$link><br/>
</$list>
```

Offtopic: you may also want to use the `$view` widget to render the title to avoid auto wikification of PascalCase titles as links: `<$link to=<<entry>>><$view field="title" /></$link>`

Comment: Thanks! There's an error in your #3: Change `<$link><<entry>></$link>` to `<$link><<currentTiddler>></$link>`.  Otherwise works great (and keeps it simple :-) )

Comment: Ah good catch, I corrected it. glad it's working for you now. the syntax and behavior of widgets and macros is quite confusing sometimes in TiddlyWiki :)